# how to get the classe names in an image classifer after predection?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I made an image classifier of 80 classes of handwritten numbers then I tested my model and it worked pretty fine, the only problem that I have now is the display of the correct names of these classes.
Dataset:
2 folders: [Train Folder===> 80 folders each has 110 images, Validation folder===> 80 folders each has 22 images]

Bellow the code I used for training, saving and testing my model:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 251, 54
#img_width, img_height = 150, 33

train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/valid'
nb_train_samples = 8800 #10435
nb_validation_samples = 1763 #2051
epochs = 30 #20 # how much time you want to train your model on the data
batch_size = 32 #16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(80)) #1
model.add(Activation('softmax')) #sigmoid

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])#categorical_crossentropy #binary_crossentropy

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=False)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('testX_2.h5') #first_try
```

last **epoche resulat**

```
Epoch 30/30
275/275 [==============================] - 38s 137ms/step - loss: 0.9406 - acc: 0.7562 - val_loss: 0.1268 - val_acc: 0.9688
```

how I tested my model:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

#result = [10,7]

def load_image(img_path, show=False):

    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(251, 54))

    img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)                    
    img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)         
    img_tensor /= 255.                                      

    if show:
        plt.imshow(img_tensor[0])                           
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()

    return img_tensor


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # load model
    model = load_model('C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/other_shit/testX_2.h5')

    # image path
    img_path = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/dataset/1.75/eeza.png'   


    # load a single image
    new_image = load_image(img_path)

    # check prediction
    pred = model.predict_classes(new_image)
    print(pred)
```

it gives me this result instead of given the name of folder:

```
[7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your problem,  the point is that its correct what the model does, but you have to build a look-up table for its answer. Your ground-truth, looks somethink like that `[0,0,0,0,1]`, a one-hot vector for example. You, the human know what this code stands for, for example `cats`.  just like that you have to build an numpy array, listing the word-embeddings in the correct order and afterwards calling it like: `class_names[prediction]`,`prediction` being your CNN-result ->`[7]`.

To sum it up, the Dense-layer in the end is giving you with `softmax-activation` a propability desnity function `P`. You are using this in comparing it with your ground-truth desnity function `q`, and calculate the difference. You just use numbers, not words, so you have to write an interpretation of the models answeres, for example in form of a lookup-table.

An example could be like:

```
pred = model.predict_classes(new_image)
labels=np.array(["cats","dogs","cars","humans"])
print(labels[pred[0]])

-> >>> cats
```

Comment: if I Understand well, i need to make 80 classes by my self :o ?

Comment: I think its quite easy and fast done, maybe you already have  a list, or a register like the name of the fodlers with the images, which you can transform into an array for example. With `names= next(os.walk(path_of_folders))[2]` you can scan a folder for all the elements in there and get the names of them. For more: [os_walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)